# An unhandled exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException' occurred in AWSSDK.dll

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried to add an object to my S3 bucket.

```
static IAmazonS3 client;
client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
{
BucketName = bucketName,
Key = keyName,
FilePath = filePath
};
PutObjectResponse response2 = client.PutObject(request);
```

The above code is used, while running the above code, I got the following error.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException' occurred in AWSSDK.dll Additional information: Error downloading regions definition file.
```

I can add the files using console and download using the C# program. No issues in that. How to resolve this error ?

Comment: The error you're seeing indicates a failure to load a description of service endpoints from AWS, but for that combination of region and service (us-east-1, S3) the service endpoint should be built into the AWSSDK.dll already. So, that's confusing. Are you using a version of the DLL supplied by AWS? Can you put your code in a try/catch and supply a stack trace?

Comment: @JimFlanagan I have solved this issue. Thanks for the inputs. The issue is with ACL's for the user which am using.